# Не удается установить Bettercap на Debian 11

Tags: linux, golang, github, debian

Пытаюсь установить bettercap по гайду. Скачал все необходимые утилиты (git build-essential libpcap-dev libusb-1.0-0-dev libnetfilter-queue-dev). Пытался установить как 1.15, так и 1.19 версии Golang. Далее командой: `go install github.com/bettercap/bettercap@latest` пытаюсь установить сам bettercap. Установку пытался делать как из корневой директории, так и из директории home/USERNAME. Установка вроде как проходит успешно, но вместо того, что указано на скриншоте после /go есть только директории /bin и /pkg. Следовательно и то, что указано на скриншоте не работает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал уже разные варианты, и `make build` в папке /home/USERNAME/go/bin (где лежит файл bettercap), но мне выдает везде один и тот же результат `make: *** Нет правила для сборки цели «build».  Останов.`

Интересно то, что в прошлый раз методом тыка я решил эту проблему, но сейчас совсем уже потерял надежду решить это сам.

Comment: ничего не понятно. сплошной текст

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Забейте на их инструкцию. Так, как делают они, собирать нельзя. Дурной тон.

Лучше выкачайте исходник через `git clone` и соберите:

```
git clone https://github.com/bettercap/bettercap
cd bettercap
make build
```

В результате в каталоге `bettercap` появится исполнимый файл `bettercap`

Если хотите установить его в `/usr/local/bin`, выполните команду `sudo make install`